# startx hot plugging monitor

Tags: server, 18.04, xorg, wayland, hotplug

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04. I installed Xorg, plugged in my monitor and started my app like this:

```
startx ./MyApplication
```

It runs perfectly, but if I unplug my monitor, run the command and then plug my monitor again, Xorg cannot detect the monitor.

Is there any solution for this? Can `startx` auto detect the monitor? If not, should I use something else, like Wayland?

Comment: Plain X.org provides very basic GUI features. If you are looking for more advanced ones, consider installing a full desktop environment. You could still launch it on demand.

Comment: I was using ubuntu desktop before and because of its bugs, wanted ti use a lighter and simpler linux, so I chose Ubuntu server, Now I just want a simple command to run Hot plugging HDMI.